# python How to insert Data to Listbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

the follownig code contains entry widgets and listbox, i need to insert data to listbox from entrywidgets. But in this code i don't know how to do this. and i don't know how to ask this.
i am sorry for my bad english.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('850x450')

def add_row(row_number):
    var1 = tk.StringVar()
    t1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var1).grid(row=row_number,column=1)
    var2 = tk.StringVar()
    t2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var2).grid(row=row_number,column=2)
    result = tk.StringVar()
    l = tk.Label(root, textvariable=result).grid(row=row_number,column=3)

    N = 3 # number of decimals that you want
    def set_label(name, index, mode):
        if var1.get() == '' or var2.get() == '':
            pass
        else:
            res = float(var1.get()) * float(var2.get())
            result.set('{number:.{digits}f}'.format(number=res, digits=N))

    var1.trace('w', set_label)
    var2.trace('w', set_label)

e1=tk.Label(root,text="mrp").grid(row=1,column=0)
e2=tk.Label(root,text="krl").grid(row=2,column=0)
e3=tk.Label(root,text="ipl").grid(row=3,column=0)
e4=tk.Label(root,text="vpl").grid(row=4,column=0)

NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 4
for row_number in range(1, NUMBER_OF_ROWS+1):
    add_row(row_number)

cols = ('Item', 'PRICE', 'QTY', 'Total')
listBox = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=cols, show='headings')

for col in cols:
    listBox.heading(col, text=col)
    listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    listBox.place(x=10, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Keep in mind, this is not a listbox its a treeview widget, to insert to treeview, you use `treeview.insert('','end',values=(...))`

Comment: i need to use buttons

Comment: The code seems hard to understand for me, but you can use `listBox.insert('','end',values=('name',var1.get(),var2.get(),result.get()))` and a button which triggers this function. Make sure to say `global var1,var2,result` on top of `add_row()`

Comment: i am understand var1.get(),var2.get() is first row, but in this code second row how can i implement.

Comment: Thats what i said, the code has a flaw there, you will have to append the entries inside of a list and then loop through the list calling the `get()`

Comment: i was implemented but error is   listBox.insert('','end',values=('mrp',var1.get(),var2.get(),result.get()))
NameError: name 'var1' is not defined

Comment: Your code is based on someother answer, so its actually hard for me to alter it to work with this case. Maybe someone else can help you out !